# How do I make bootstrap vue collapsibles work on ul and li folder structure

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-vue

I am using the HTML and CSS to create a folder like structure as in this link:

https://codepen.io/sazzad/pen/gEEKQb

I want the items to collapse and open when clicking on them. This includes a couple nested bootstrap collapsibles. For some reason they are all triggered together and the entire system is not working as expected.

This is the code I have:

```
<div class="tree">
  <ul>
    <li v-b-toggle.collapse-1>
      <i class="fa fa-folder-open" /> Project
      <b-collapse id="collapse-1">
        <ul>
          <li v-b-toggle.collapse-2>
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open" /> Opened Folder <span>- 15kb</span>
            <b-collapse id="collapse-2">
              <ul>
                <li v-b-toggle.collapse-3>
                  <i class="fa fa-folder-open" /> css
                  <b-collapse id="collapse-3">
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-code" /> CSS Files <span>- 3kb</span>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </b-collapse>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <i class="fa fa-folder" /> Folder close <span>- 10kb</span>
                </li>
                <li><i class="fab fa-html5" /> index.html</li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-picture-o" /> favicon.ico</li>
              </ul>
            </b-collapse>
          </li>
          <li>
            <i class="fa fa-folder" /> Folder close <span>- 420kb</span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </b-collapse>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle link that shows the problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/p6fj58tv/

Comment: The problem is you are wrapping the collapse trigger over the new collapse. ```<li v-b-toggle.collapse-2>
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open" /> Opened Folder <span>- 15kb</span>
            <b-collapse id="collapse-2">```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the nested collapse was also a part of the first or top most trigger element

https://jsfiddle.net/twj28z1m/

I changed this to

```
          <li v-b-toggle.collapse-2>
            <i class="fa fa-folder-open" /> Opened Folder <span>- 15kb</span>
            <b-collapse id="collapse-2">
```

this

```
 <li >
        <span v-b-toggle.collapse-1>
          <i class="fa fa-folder-open" /> Project
          </span>
         <b-collapse id="collapse-2">
```

That change should fix it on the first level. you can use the same approach ahead for other elements